# jQuery - Able to disable checkboxes on condition, but odd problem

Tags: jquery

I found some jQuery code as a result of a Google search that allowed me to disable specific classes of checkboxes based on user input of a single select box. I works great and I even added some code to grey out the text describing the text box. However, I use PHP (a session variable in particular) and MySQL to repopulate the select box' value if the user goes back/revisits the page and when that happens the checkboxes are no longer greyed out based on the value of the select box. I presume it's because the function requires the user to actually select an option, not for it to be the selected option on page load. Is there any way around this? See code below:

```
$(function(){
  var arrValPS = [ "3-Year-Old Program","Prekindergarten", "Kindergarten" ];
```

$("#grade").change(function(){
  var valToCheck = String($(this).val());

```
if ( jQuery.inArray(valToCheck,arrValPS) == -1 )
{
```

$(".psc").attr("disabled", "true"); 
  jQuery('.pscdiv').fadeTo(500,0.2);

```
}
else
{
        $(".psc").removeAttr ( "disabled" ); 
        jQuery('.pscdiv').fadeTo(500,1);   
}
```

});
});
$(function(){
      var arrValLS = [ "1st Grade","2nd Grade","3rd Grade","4th Grade","5th Grade" ];

```
  $("#grade").change(function(){
  var valToCheck = String($(this).val());

    if ( jQuery.inArray(valToCheck,arrValLS) == -1 )
    {
  $(".lsc").attr("disabled", "true"); 
  jQuery('.lscdiv').fadeTo(500,0.2);

    }
    else
    {
            $(".lsc").removeAttr ( "disabled" ); 
            jQuery('.lscdiv').fadeTo(500,1);   
    }        
  });
});
```

$(function(){
      var arrValMS = [ "6th Grade","7th Grade","8th Grade" ];

```
  $("#grade").change(function(){
  var valToCheck = String($(this).val());

    if ( jQuery.inArray(valToCheck,arrValMS) == -1 )
    {
  $(".msc").attr("disabled", "true"); 
  jQuery('.mscdiv').fadeTo(500,0.2);

    }
    else
    {
            $(".msc").removeAttr ( "disabled" ); 
            jQuery('.mscdiv').fadeTo(500,1);   
    }        
  });
});
```

An example of the checkboxes:

```
<div class="pscdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="psc" name="camps[]" value="psc_1"/><label for="psc_1">AM - Week 1: Description Here</label></div>
<div class="pscdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="psc" name="camps[]" value="psc_2"/><label for="psc_2">PM - Week 1: Description Here</label></div>
<div class="lscdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="psc" name="camps[]" value="psc_3"/><label for="lsc_1">AM - Week 2: Description Here</label></div>
<div class="lscdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="psc" name="camps[]" value="psc_4"/><label for="lsc_2">AM - Week 2: Description Here</label></div>
<div class="mscdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="psc" name="camps[]" value="psc_5"/><label for="msc_1">PM - Week 2: Description Here</label></div>
<div class="mscdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="psc" name="camps[]" value="psc_6"/><label for="msc_2">AM - Week 3: Description Here</label></div>
```

---

Update #1

I have tried Abdullah's code below with zero success. I have also tried the other suggestions with zero success. A couple people have said I could use less code basically, but everything I've tried hasn't worked whereas what I have now works perfectly except for the one nagging issue that I posted this question about. As much as I would like to thin it down it's way more important to me to get past the problem first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really needs to be refactored further but just to answer your question, you need to call the same code on page load so move it into a function and call it on page load as well as on the change event:

```
$(function(){
    $("#grade").change(checkVals);
    checkVals(); // run it on page load
});

function checkVals() {
    var valToCheck = String($("#grade").val());
    if ( jQuery.inArray(valToCheck,arrValPS) == -1 )
    {
        $(".psc").attr("disabled", "true"); 
        jQuery('.pscdiv').fadeTo(500,0.2);
    }
    else
    {
        $(".psc").removeAttr ( "disabled" ); 
        jQuery('.pscdiv').fadeTo(500,1);   
    }        

    var arrValLS = [ "1st Grade","2nd Grade","3rd Grade","4th Grade","5th Grade" ];
    if ( jQuery.inArray(valToCheck,arrValLS) == -1 )
    {
        $(".lsc").attr("disabled", "true"); 
        jQuery('.lscdiv').fadeTo(500,0.2);
    }
    else
    {
        $(".lsc").removeAttr ( "disabled" ); 
        jQuery('.lscdiv').fadeTo(500,1);   
    }        

    var arrValMS = [ "6th Grade","7th Grade","8th Grade" ];
    if ( jQuery.inArray(valToCheck,arrValMS) == -1 )
    {
        $(".msc").attr("disabled", "true"); 
        jQuery('.mscdiv').fadeTo(500,0.2);
    }
    else
    {
        $(".msc").removeAttr ( "disabled" ); 
        jQuery('.mscdiv').fadeTo(500,1);   
    } 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm just not understanding it. I have no experience with jQuery so unfortunately I can't make enough sense of the code to do anything custom. I tried your code and it didn't work, even when I went to the page in a new session (the other code worked fine then). Thanks for your help.

Comment: This should run on page load, to test it, put this right after your call to checkVals(): `alert('This is on page load');`. Now when you refresh the page you should see that popup.

Comment: I finally got around to looking at this after a break from this project. I was playing with a lot of jQuery on another project I'm simultaneously working on so maybe it all started to click a little bit finally. Your code works perfectly, I just had to add one line that specified the first set of options from my drop-down box. 

(which was var arrValPS = [ "3-Year-Old Program","Prekindergarten", "Kindergarten" ];)

In retrospect I should have given the code for the select box - sorry about that. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fire a change event on the element you are bingind to when the document is ready:

```
$(function() {
    $("#grade").change();
});
```

By the way, you could have all that different cases on the same 'change' handler.

Comment: How would I do the change event when the document is ready? Does page position of the script matter in this case?

I figured I could do it all in one handler and I even took a crack at it, but alas I failed. As I said to Abdullah I have no jQuery experience so I was taking a shot in the dark when I tried it.

Thanks.

Comment: Whatever is inside a $(function() {  }) runs when the page is ready. In your case you have 3 such blocks plus 1 more I proposed. There is no guaranteed order on their execution. I suggest you move all your code into a single $(function() {  }) and run $("#grade").change(); as the last thing there. I think @Abdullah Jibaly solution is better though. Less hacky at least...

Answer (score 0):

Call that function on your Page Load event solve your problem.

Comment: include it in $().ready(function(){ //your code goes here });